# Finding last occurrence of a pattern with lookaround

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the path `../dir1/dir2/dir3/filename.txt` and want to extract just `filename` between the final `\` and `.` using regex. The file extension will also not always be `.txt`.

Currently I am doing `(?<=\/).+(?=\.)` but selects from the first `\`, including the directory names. I would love this to just be match-based and not using groups. Oh and using ECMA regex if that's important.

Comment: sometimes it's simpler to break it into pieces: `strPath.split(/\//).pop().split(/\./)[0]` is a lot easier to read/maintain than rx foo.

Comment: I don't know about Javascript, but some languages provide methods or functions to extract the filename and extension from the fully-qualified path. In Ruby, for example, if `f = "../dir1/dir2/dir3/filename.txt"`,  `File.basename(f).delete(File.extname(f)) #=> "filename"`.

Comment: Would you want `"dog"` returned if the fully-qualified filename had no extension, such as `"../dir/dog"` What would you want returned if it were `"../dir/cat.tar.gz"`? What about hidden files, such as `"../dir/.pig.pen"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below regex to achieve your purpose:

```
([\w-]+)\..*$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`([\w-]+)`** - Capturing group that matches one or more (+) word characters (\w) or hyphens (-). Usually filenames contains [`\w`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#chars) characters so I used that but if it contains other special characters feel free to amend it as per your need.
- **`\.`** - matches a literal dot character.
- **`.*`** - matches any character (.) zero or more times (*).
- **`$`** - matches end of line. So basically the full regex matches any string that contains a word (consisting of one or more word characters or hyphens) followed by a dot and any characters until the end of the line. The word before the dot is captured for later use and this capturing group gives you your desired `filename`.

[image]

```js
const regex = /.*?([\w-]+)\..*$/gm;

const str = `../dir1/dir2/dir3/filename1.tar.gz
../dir1/dir2/dir3/filename2.tar`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

***[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/y4Cw4w/1)***

**Alternative Way:(Using Javascript functions)**

```js
let paths = `../dir1/dir2/dir3/filename1.tar.gz
../dir1/dir2/dir3/filename2.tar`;

paths.split('\n').forEach(path => console.log(path.  
split('/').pop().split('.').shift()));

/* 
* split('/').pop() - splits the path into an array using the forward slash (/) as the separator
and removes and returns the last element of the array.  

* split('.').shift() - splits the filename into an array using the dot (.) as the separator, 
and removes and returns the first element of the array.
* NOTE: paths.split('\n') might not be your exact requirement. I used it to showcase.
*/
```

Comment: Don't forget that basenames are not required to have an extension.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks. If that is the case then, ***[this](https://regex101.com/r/ToR8q1/1)*** will help. Also I believe the OP has mentioned **extract just filename between the final \ and `.`**, that's why I didn't added this but yes if required I can do.

Comment: Thank you! Both these answers were great :)

Comment: I love this answer. Very detailed, several examples, and excellent explanations. Awesome work.

Answer (score 2):

If you match the regular expression

```
\/(?:(\.?[^./][^/]*)\.[^./]+|(\.?[^./]+))$
```

either:

- there is a filename extension, in which case capture group 1 will hold the basename without the extension and capture group 2 will be empty; or
- the basename has no extension, in which case capture group 2 will hold the basename and capture group 1 will be empty.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o06A0h/1)

We can break this expression down as follows.

```
\/         # match a forward slash 
(?:        # begin non-capture group
  (        # begin capture group 1
     \.?   # optionally match a period (for hidden files)
    [^/]+  # match one or more chars other than (`^`) a forward slash
  )        # end capture group 1
  \.       # match a period
  [^./]+   # match one or more chars other than a period or forward slash
|          # or
  (        # begin capture group 2
     \.?   # optionally match a period (for hidden files)
    [^./]+ # match one or more chars other than a period or forward slash
  )        # end capture group 2
)          # end non-capture group
$          # match the end of the string
```

You may also wish to hover (the cursor, not your person) over different parts of the expression at the link to obtain explanations of their functions.

---

If it were known that the basename had an extension the regular expression would simplify in the obvious way, with a single capture group:

```
(\.?[^/]+)\.[^./]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oSXPZS/1)

Comment: Thanks so much! This and the other answer both worked well for me :)!